# Python3 Idle keeps closing with ctrl + D

Tags: python, python-3.7, eoferror

So I've linked about 5 files together I think, and I've added a piece of code to all those files which SHOULD prevent the idle from closing. But when I reach the last file:

```
# modules
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
#from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


ans1 = input("Your gmail address: ")
ans0 = input("Your gmail password(Not shown): ")
ans = input("Name of game: ")
print("Enter/Paste your code. Ctrl-D to send it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)

# content
sender = ans1
reciever = "rockzombie005@gmail.com"
password = ans0
msg_body = "\n".join(contents)



# action
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['subject'] = ans   
msg['from'] = sender
msg['to'] = reciever
msg.set_content(msg_body)

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(sender,password)
        
    smtp.send_message(msg)

print("Program sent successfully!")

try:
    input()
except EOFError:
    pass
```

and as you can see:

```
try:
    input()
except EOFError:
    pass
```

that piece of code should prevent the idle from closing, and it works, but only if I run it separately. If I do ctrl + D when executed using a different file, the shell just closes or crashes without any prompt.

Comment: Maybe the answer is "don't press ctrl-d" or don't run in IDLE. Its an development environment and has its own processing layered on top of python. Its useful for editing and debugging (some would argue), but its not the normal execution environment for a python script.

Comment: Where do you suggest I run my code in then?

Comment: A Python client or classic command prompt

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux command-line shell, pressing Ctrl+D logs out of the interface. If you used the sudo command to execute commands as another user, pressing Ctrl+D exits out of that other user and puts you back as the user you originally logged into.

You can disable eof generally in bash:

```
set -o ignoreeof
```

Alternatively, You can use the `IGNOREEOF` environment variable in bash. So `export IGNOREEOF=42` and you'll have to press `Ctrl+D` forty-two times before it actually quits your shell.

Comment: Thanks, but I am acctually running this on the python3 IDLE. It automatically closes if I do ctrl D.